# Is it possible to draw an svg path to the periphery of a circle

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

Say I have an svg circle and I'd like to draw an svg path around it, like if it would be it's stroke. I know I can draw it with stroke, but for stroke I can't apply marker-end, can I?

What I want to achieve is to have a path element alongside with the circle on the peripheral, and at the end/start of the path I would have a marker-arrow and I would animate this path alongside of the circle in a round fashion denoting some kind of self-loop.

Thanks

Comment: do you have your current code (that doesn't work) as an example?

Comment: I don't have a working sample because I don't know how to draw a path on the circle peripheral hence this question.